# Problem when download dompdf in magento 2.4.1

Tags: composer, magento2.4.1

Hi am trying to install dompdf in Magento 2.4.1 using composer v1 but no success
[image]

Comment: If you need install in app/code/ folder. Please check this link :- https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-dompdf

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below command :

```
composer require weprovide/magento2-module-dompdf --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
composer global require --no-update ""weprovide/magento2-module-dompdf""

composer global update
```

If you still get the error, the version conflict cannot be solved and you can't install all your tools globally. Install dompdf in your project instead, or in a separate directory